# addProximityAlert is not working if Location service is disabled

Tags: android, location

I'm using `LocationManager#addProximityAlert` function to alert the user when enter the range of some places, if the location service is enabled everything works fine and I get the notifications, but when the location is disabled I get nothing. I need to receive the alerts even if the location is not enabled, here is my code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE, MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
            new LocationListener());
public void prepareNotifications() {
// nearProductsLocs is an array of locations 
for (int i = 0; i < nearProductsLocs.length; i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "order" + i + " " nearProductsLocs[i]);
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // add addProximityAlerts
    Location loc = nearProducts[i];
    addProximityAlert(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
}
}
private void addProximityAlert(Double latitude, Double longtitude, int productId) {
Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
intent.putExtra("productId", productId);
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
sContext.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longtitude, POINT_RADIUS, PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION,proximityIntent);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
sContext.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
}
```

and my `ProximityIntentReceiver` is here:

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent xintent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    Boolean entering = xintent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
    int productId = xintent.getIntExtra("productId", 0);
    Log.d("productId", "" + productId);

    if (entering) {

        Intent offerIntent = new Intent(context, Item.class);
        offerIntent.putExtra("productId", productId);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, productId, offerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "Nearby product!",System.currentTimeMillis());
        createNotification(myNotification);
        myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Monim", "Check this amazing Product!", pIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(productId, myNotification);
    }

}
```

Comment: "I need to receive the alerts even if the location is not enabled" -- by definition, that is not possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean location service "gps", the device can still use wifi and mobile data to get its current location, am I right ?

Comment: According to the docs for `addProximityAlert()`, "Internally, this method uses both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER." My guess is that it will not work without GPS access.